# Removing HTML entities in strings

Tags: c#, html, encoding

I have text that is retrieved on a linkbutton press:

[image]

When I press the button I am getting the following returned:

```
Test UAT&#39;s for release 2.2.0
```

It looks like HMTL entities are being retrieved. How do I turn these back into normal strings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to remove the Html entities, actually the string that you are showing here is `HTML Encoded` so you just need to do `Html Decoding` to get it in normal form.

For that you have [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) method.

```
string normalString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString);
```

If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher then you can also use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode.aspx)

Comment: must reference `System.Web.dll`

Comment: Please, take mention about WebUtility.HtmlDecode as primary way. It is better, because does not require System.Web.dll

Answer (score 3):

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) to decode the string.